# Programa não aparece na barra de ferramentas ao iniciar

Tags: c#

Olá, tenho o seguinte erro: ao abrir o programa, o ícone dele não aparece na taskbar, e antes isso não acontecia. Passou a acontecer agora!

Tá aqui a imagem, ao abrir o programa (Olhe a Taskbar):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E só passa a aparecer depois de clicar no programa (Olhe a Taskbar):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não tem nada a ver com a propriedade ShowInTaskbar, pois já está true.

Alguma solução pro problema? Obs: O FormBorderStyle está em None, esse é o tema que eu escrevi. (Já tive esse problema de não aparecer na taskbar ao iniciar, utilizando outros temas, mas esse problema só me veio aparecer agora.)

Comment: conseguiu resolver o seu problema?

Comment: Parece que se resolveu sozinho... Você já passou por isso?
Projeto: https://github.com/LucasNaja/deck-generator
Versão web: https://github.com/LucasNaja/deck-royale

Comment: não era nada relacionado ao debug?